# Outswing Door Strike

Tags: doors

I have doors I would like to electronically control remotely.  I have seen  door strikes in older NYC apartments that I thought would be perfect: until I remembered the target doors are outswing.

Is there a solution similar to an inswing electronic door strike for outswing doors?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are outswing electronic strikes. Sometimes you see a cover plate bolted onto the door to prevent tampering with these. There are also magnetic locks that can be installed in both in and outswing configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic locks are easy to install, but you’ll need to decide if the lock is going to be “Fail Safe” or “Fail Secure”.

Fail Safe locks means the magnetic lock OPENS during a power outage and Fail Secure means the lock STAYS LOCKED during a power outage.

You will also need to extend a wire to the lock (through the door) or to the strike plate.